# Pass image via axios request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

So I need to pass an image(and text) from a react component to an api.

I have this code in my react api:

```
export const addProject = (name, imgs) => {
    var imgsArray = [];
    Object.keys(imgs).map(x => imgsArray.push(imgs[x]));
    console.log(imgsArray); //Will print(with 3 files passed): (3) [File(179582), File(32123), File(122404)]
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("name", name);
    formData.append("images", imgsArray);
    return axios.post('/api/addProject',formData,{ headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }});
}
```

So far we have an image object and have passed it in a formData object via a post request to the node js api.

This calls the function below(removed most of the code as it's irrelevant to my problem:

```
router.post('/addProject', upload.array('file'), (req, res) => {
    console.log(typeof req.body.images); //Will print out string

    console.log(req.body.images); //Will print(with 3 files passed): [object File],[object File],[object File]
});
```

So I'm passing the file through but it's been converted to a string. I've spent ages trying to fix this to no avail.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are talking about array, you need to use `[]`, following code may help you

```
export const addProject = (name, imgs) => {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("name", name);
    Object.keys(imgs).forEach(x => formData.append("images[]", x));
    return axios.post('/api/addProject', formData, { headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }});
}
```

Comment: Oh no wait, now it's giving me an array with one object, a string.

Comment: `[ '[object File],[object File],[object File]' ]`